# Spring boot start up #!NL!# using intellij

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm getting the below error when trying to start my spring boot app locally? It runs that much a suddenly stops with `#!NL!#`, no error or anything, any advice? Thanks

```
12:20:25,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
12:20:25,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
12:20:25,839 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/billy.charter/Workspace/wfm-linking-tickets/out/production/resources/logback.xml]
12:20:25,917 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ContextNameAction - Setting logger context name as [wfm-linking-tickets]
12:20:25,917 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
12:20:25,933 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
12:20:25,933 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.dish] to DEBUG
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.dish] to false
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.dish]
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cxf] to ERROR
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache.cxf] to false
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.cxf]
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
12:20:25,948 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@e81285 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
#!NL!#
```

Comment: Can you start the application without your logback.xml? Mostly there is an issue with the logging configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the question, I ended up upgrading to to spring 2.0, all I needed to do was do a clean (to get rid of my spring 1.5 libraries) and it built and ran fine.